# Compare Delphi Exception Handlers

Tags: delphi

How would you compare [MadExcept](http://www.madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm) to [EurekaLog](http://www.eurekalog.com/index_delphi.php) as an Exception handler for your Delphi application?

Why would you pick one over the other?

Are there any other exception handlers for Delphi that should be considered in addition to these two?

---

Well the answer was between Smasher and Mark, who both had good info in their comparisons but ended up picking one and the other. So it was a toss up - and I gave the answer to Smasher, just because he was the first of the two to answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We did compare these two before deciding to use EurekaLog. It looked a lot more configurable and also seems to have the more professional support. Nothing bad to tell about EurekaLog so far. It works great and isn't too hard to set up and configure the way you like it.

Comment: We have Eurekalog in production. Works very well for us. Sending automated bug reports with stack trace and whole shebang.

Answer (score 12):

After comparing the two I went with MadExcept.  At the time (~5 years ago) there were some difference that were important to me but looking at their websites now it looks like the feature differences no longer exist.

One of the items that swayed me was [Stack Tracking methods](http://help.madshi.net/TraceMethods.htm) on the Madshi site. A previous company I worked for had a custom execption object for VB6.  I saw some of the pain they went through and my impression is that Madshi is a really smart guy who knows what he is doing.

I did inherit a project that used EureakLog and actually used both for about 2 years.  In the end I converted that project to use MadExcept.  I was more comfortable with it and preferred the MadExpect bug reports.

I have had very good luck with support on the Madshi forums - some times with the answer from Madshi himself.  If you take a look you will see he is very active there.

I have looked at the JCL stuff, but both MadExcept and EureakLog as so cheap, professional, and work well that I didn't even think twice before going with MadExcept.

Comment: I think EurekaLog has more features and the GUI is more polished then MadShi madExcept, but it is also VERY buggy. The support for EurekaLog is also very poor. I will consider MadShi when I will go for the next upgrade.

Comment: We actually tried MadExcept. First impression was good. But then we discovered that it don't support callstacks from inc-files. That is a requirement for us.

Answer (score 8):

We are a team that use JCL for catch exceptions and log them with callstack to a log-file.
It works fine.

Comment: And it is free and open source. It also means that if you want you can change the look of the exception dialog completely. http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/

Comment: Interesting. Are there any good examples or descriptions of how to use just JclDebug and JclHookExcept together simply for this purpose?

Comment: Adding the ExceptionDialog unit that comes with JCL and turning on enough debug information would do the trick. JclDebug can use different sources, internal and external, of debug information. See http://www.gnegg.ch/2002/12/jcldebug/

Comment: Interesting! The framework currently used in our application was written by a former employed. We just used it and never change it as it works. The downside is that we have to compile it with debuginfo on. Would it work equally to turn off debuginfo and use the map-file instead for JCL and generate a callstack on exception ?

Comment: Yes, an external file like a map file or jcl's own external debug format would also suffice.

Answer (score 4):

[JCL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcl/) has it's own exception handler, it's free of course and it's quite nice.

Comment: It's JCL, not JVCL (nothing *visual* about an exception framework)

Comment: Can you do a very short comparison with EurekaLog and madExcept please?

Comment: It seems that JCL Debug does not have a standalone GUI to configure the tool. https://blog.dummzeuch.de/2014/03/08/using-jcldebug/

Answer (score 2):

There is also JclDebug, part of the jedi code library. I don't know how it compares to MadExecpt and EurekaLog since I never used any of these two.

Answer (score 1):

On a very big project I tried both the trials and I was able to compile at the first attempt with MadExcept while compilation failed wit EurekaLog. My colleague by the way could compile with both, so it was a machine dependant problem. Btw they ship with similar good features, a must have for every company.

Comment: Yes. EurekaLog is more buggy than madExcept.

Comment: We finally adopted EurekaLog, even if i cannot recall the reason now, in the years it helped us find the cause of many erors like Access Violations. It is a very useful tool. The only point i do not like is that from time to time it does not work (for example some Access Violation errors are not logged and the app behave like EurekaLog is non active). Overall an exceptino logger is a must with Delphi!

Comment: Yes. It is what I observed also. They fix many bugs but they introduce the same amount back, in each new version. If you want to report bugs, the Support is simply rude.