# Delphi general exception catch

Tags: delphi, exception

In .NET WinForms there is a such tip that I can catch any uncatched exception on the application level.

Could it can be done also in Delphi - in the case that the source of the exception can't be bound with try/except block.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can attach an eventhandler to `Application.OnException` and handle any unhandled exception there.

Depending on your Delphi version, you can either

- attach and implement an eventhandler entirely in code in your Main Form, dpr or wherever you see fit in the form of `Application.OnException := DoApplicationException`.
- drop a `TApplicationEvents` component on your main form, double click the OnException event and implement your code.

Comment: There are also lots of very powerful tools from third parties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918221/delphi-application-error-logging-in-the-field