# Runtime error 216

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a system that recently do not run delphi program and shows runtime error 216. What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: You must post some source code if you expect anyone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 3):

[Runtime error](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/delphiruntimeerrors_xml.html) [216](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/delphifatalerrors_xml.html) is an 'Access Violation'; there's code accessing invalid memory.

Like Brad says, you have to provide some information for someone to make a guess. And/or you can install a [3rd party exception-handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931833/compare-delphi-exception-handlers) and if it catches the exception examine the information it provides to isolate the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error is a general protection fault.  It can be caused by just about anything.